# Troubleshooting "Can't connect ..." from MySQL slave to master

Tags: mysql, mariadb, master-slave-replication

Although I can connect from slave to master via a command-line mysql client, my slave can't connect to the master as part of its replication task. `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` cites a "Permission denied" error:

> Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replicant@dbmaster:5000' - retry-time: 60  maximum-retries: 86400  message: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'dbmaster' (13 "Permission denied")

**I've checked the user permissions as well as a command-line client connection. What else can I check?**

The user has `SELECT` and `REPLICATION SLAVE` permissions on the master:

```bash
mysql -h dbmaster -P 5000 -u replicant "-p$PASS" --ssl -e 'SHOW GRANTS'
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# | Grants for replicant@192.168.187.101                                                                                                                   |
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
# | GRANT SELECT, REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO `replicant`@`192.168.187.101` IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '[HASH-REDACTED]' REQUIRE SSL |
# +--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And I've set up the slave to use the same username, password, host, port, ssl:

```bash
cat <<-EOF | mysql
STOP SLAVE;
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_SSL=1, MASTER_DELAY=259200,
MASTER_HOST='dbmaster', MASTER_PORT=5000,
MASTER_USER='replicant', MASTER_PASSWORD='$PASS',
MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.041117', MASTER_LOG_POS=733093730;
START SLAVE;
EOF
```

*The server is running Mariadb 10.3.*

Comment: I've also tried just changing the password multiple times: `STOP SLAVE; CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_PASSWORD = '...'; START SLAVE;`, but the error is the same, and the slave status shows `Slave_IO_Running: Connecting`

Answer (score -1):

cat <<-EOF | mysql    Line OK
STOP SLAVE; Line OK

CHANGE MASTER 'AnyName4Slave' TO MASTER_HOST = '',MASTER_PORT=3306, MASTER_USER = 'user', MASTER_PASSWORD = 'password' ,MASTER_LOG_FILE='mysql-bin.041117', MASTER_LOG_POS=733093730;

START SLAVE 'AnyName4Slave';
EOF

Comment: Can you explain your answer? I'm not sure how closely this is meant to apply to my environment. For example, my server is using the nonstandard port 5000, as evidenced by my the connection established for my successful `SHOW GRANTS` command.

Comment: use your own port , rest of slave connection is same

Comment: can you help explain the important differences between your command and the command that I shared in my post? (I don't see any material differences except (1) the fact that you use a name for the slave and (2) the fact that you are using different values than I used for port, host, user, and password.)